# css media landscape and portrait

Tags: html, css

Why I add the css media below that, and pixel effect isn't same on nexus 5 of two configuration. It's seemed two-thirds. (The size of 60px in portrait seems as the 40px in landscape).

What concept should I know? (I really very confuse)

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)and (orientation:portrait)`

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)and (orientation:landscape)`

**UPDATED QUESTION**

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgvpszrt/2/

The height and text-size are not same in picture.

[image]

//---------------------------

After I fix code to https://jsfiddle.net/Lgvpszrt/3/, it's working.

But I don't know the concept.

Comment: Avoid trying to define media queries for all devices.  See [Flexbox](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks, I will study Flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might because of pixel density difference. Please take a look at this article from Mozila to have a better understanding regarding view port and pixel on mobile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: Great article for understanding pixel. I also haven't really gotten it till now

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be combining meta-viewport tag syntax and @media rules. Try this stuff out.  https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/rLnL27e4/

```
body {
  background: red;
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background: orange;
  }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background: pink;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background: lime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your replay,I update my quest.  My confuse is the height is not same.